# How do I run storybook as a git submodule without interfering with the main project?

Tags: reactjs, git, storybook, react-scripts

In order to run storybook, I have to `npm install` the project and `npm run storybook`. Problem is, this project is a submodule of another project, with its own node_modules folder. When I `npm start` the main project, it crashes due to some random dependency from node_modules of the inner storybook submodule. So, how can I exclude the submodule's node_modules folder from the webpack's inner build process? (I use react-scripts). I don't want to erase node_modules and `npm install` everytime I want to run storybook, and I want to work on it **as a git submodule**.

Comment: any solution you found